# Event triggered once not each time the script is running

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

I'm using the script below to be notified by e-mail when myhost is down.

I'm having this script running in crontab each minute.

**The problem:** whenever my host is down it alerts me each minute that the host is down (triggered by crontab each minute).

**What I want to do:**

1. When my host is down I'd like to be alerted only once. So if the host is down for 30 minutes, I would like to be alerted once not 30 times.
  2.

When myhost is up again, I'd like to have another alert that myhost is back again.

Thank you.

```
#!/bin/bash
ping -c 1 www.myhost.com > /dev/null 2>&1
status=$?
while true;
do

if [ "$status" -eq 0 ]; then
 echo "OK"
 exit 0
else
 #echo "Ping NOK"
 echo "myhost is down" | /usr/bin/mail -s "It happened: myhost is down" myaddr@gmail.com
 exit 1
fi
done
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your script that looks like an attempt to implement the "only notify once every 30 minutes" rule, or the "up" notification. What about looking at a tool like [Icinga](http://icinga.org) or [Zabbix](http://zabbix.com) for this sort of functionality, so that you can put it into a configuration file (or web UI) rather than the code itself?

Comment: Indeed the script is not containing such things, this is what I'm working to create. I want to code them manually.

Comment: Great! When you've written that code, do ask questions about any problems you're having with it!  :-)  But in the mean time, do you have a question?

Answer (score 1):

You have to store some state outside of the script to see in the next independet run that the e-mail has been already sent. Maybe in case of host down you put a file somewhere. When in case of host down there is already a file and it is not too old, skip sending the e-mail.

It is not possible to have the state (maybe a flag) encapsulated inside the script because on each execution (via cron) this will be a new instance of the script having its own variables.

Another thing: The `while` loop is superfluous. The loop will always be exited at the first iteration.

Comment: I was thinking to write a flag outside the script in a file. But is it possible to do it inside the script without writing on the filesystem? Thanks for the while tip.

Comment: @fastlearner — You have to write the information to the file system.  I suppose you could edit the script itself to record the last status and send email when the status changes, or too long has elapsed since the previous change and you want to affirm the current status in an email, but that’s not how it is normally done.

Comment: Is it possible to keep the script running in the background in a loop? Just to avoid using crontab each minute?

Comment: Yes, you can use ```sleep``` in each iteration. But you must restart it on reboot and a cronjob is more reliable in case of failure.

Comment: Is it possible to give an example? I don't get that because sleep just pauses the script for a certain amount of time, I don't understand how can sleep keep the script in the background and run it.

Comment: ```sleep``` is not for keeping in backgroud but for delay if you want it to run only once a minute. You can run it for example in the background by adding ```&``` to the command line. You have many questions. I think it would be good to read a book about shell scripting.